# Reorder Records Display as Empty

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com), Apache, and PHP7.

I created a custom Plugin using the Builder.

I'm able to add records, everything is working good. Except if I press the `Reorder records` button it display a list of empty records.

---

Is there a guide on how to set this up?

I'm looking at:
 https://octobercms.com/docs/database/traits#nested-tree
https://octobercms.com/docs/api/october/rain/database/traits/nestedtree

I added to the Model:

`use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\NestedTree;`

And to the database columns:

`parent_id`, `nest_left`, `nest_right`, `nest_depth`.

---

Where do I put `$table->integer('parent_id')->nullable();`?

If I put it in the Model it gives error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$table' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)`.

---

Records

[image: Reorder Records Button]

---

Reorder Records: Empty List

[image: Empty Records]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you do not need to use `nestable` as we are not dealing with `trees` and there seems a guide but it is brief.

We can be just happy with `\October\Rain\Database\Traits\Sortable` for sorting only as we do not need `tree`  we can skip adding these

```
use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\NestedTree;
parent_id, nest_left, nest_right, nest_depth
```

you need a specific column name `sort_order` if we use `trait` however we can change this if we need by defining `const SORT_ORDER = 'my_sort_order';` in our `model`.

As you have already build tables you can `update your table definition using builder plugin` and add `sort_order` field to your table.

> or manually you can use this script and add it to `version.yaml` file [ plugins\hardiksatasiya\demotest\updates ( respectively in your plugin ) ]

**version.yaml**

```
1.0.19:
    - 'Updated table hardiksatasiya_demotest_sorting'
    - builder_table_update_hardiksatasiya_demotest_sorting_3.php
```

**builder_table_update_hardiksatasiya_demotest_sorting.php**

```
<?php namespace HardikSatasiya\DemoTest\Updates;

use Schema;
use October\Rain\Database\Updates\Migration;

class BuilderTableUpdateHardiksatasiyaDemotestSorting extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('hardiksatasiya_demotest_sorting', function($table)
        {
            $table->integer('sort_order')->default(0)->change();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('hardiksatasiya_demotest_sorting', function($table)
        {
            $table->integer('sort_order')->default(null)->change();
        });
    }
}
```

> Now, add Trait to your Model

```
<?php namespace HardikSatasiya\DemoTest\Models;

use Model;

/**
 * Model
 */
class Sort extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Sortable;

    ....
```

Now either you can add manually all the needed files or use builder tool for it.

I prefer using Builder to add a controller and needed file

> Make sure you tick `Reorder behavior`

[image]

> To show name in reorder list, we need to set this property `from which field we need to derive a name` to show in sorting list.

[image]

> It will look like this with `name` as a sort attribute name

[image]

> Side Menu [ plugin.yaml and controllers]

[image]

[image]

If you have further doubts please comment.

Comment: I added the `sort_order` Integer column. Added the `use Traits Sortable` to Model. Checked the `Reorder controller behavior`. Added `attribute name` to controller. It shows the Sort list and names, I can drag and drop. But it does not save when I click `Return to the list`. It also does not show the blue side menu `Relation` and `Sort Order`.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the Sort page, the blue side menu is missing. https://i.imgur.com/oy4XZ28.png

Comment: you need to add menu from the plugin builder it will not come directly or it is not part of sorting. if you want to add manually I added pics of it.

Comment: I am not sure it's not saving the data, you added `$table->integer('sort_order')->default(0)` default to `0`

Comment: means in very first try to add `sort_order` manually for existing records in DB, then it will automatically assign `sort_order` and started saving it, i face that issue to0 :)